# Titanium Mobile Push Notifications callback not fired

Tags: callback, notifications, titanium, push, titanium-mobile

I asked this question on the developers forum too, but as my time is running out I hoped posting on stackoverflow might be quicker.

Currently I am able to receive push notifications and I want to send some extra data along, after searching around I concluded that this should be possible. The idea is to set the messages from a users inbox (in the app) when a push notification is fired, so a users gets a push notification that says "New message" and along with it is the message send in a different key which is supposed to be saved in the `Applications.Properties` when the push notifications `callback` function is called.

However, the `callback` function is never triggered. The notifications are send, the badge is set to what my php script does so is the message. To test if the callback was triggered I changed the badge and message to hardcoded values (see below), I got this code from mainly from ios muncher but I assumed that the alert in the `callback` would be the one shown to the user.

A different thing I noticed, I only receive push notifications when the user is not using the app, so when it is running in the background. When a user is using the app push notifications are not shown, I thought that this might be because the callback is not triggered.

Thanks in advance for all kind help.

Below some code:

```
Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({  
    types: [  
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,  
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
            Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND  
        ],  
        success:function(e){
            var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;  
            Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: "+deviceToken);  

            //alert('device token is' +e.deviceToken);  
            var request = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

            request.open("POST","http://*********/sendToken.php");  
            var params = {  
                "token": e.deviceToken,
                "username": authProperties[0].username,
                "userId": authProperties[0].userId    
            };  

            request.send(params);

            Ti.API.info("Push notification types:         "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);  
    Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled:"+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);  
},  
error:function(e){
    alert("Error during registration: "+e.error);

    Ti.API.info("Error during registration: "+e.error);  
},
callback:function(e)  
{  
    // called when a push notification is received.  
    //Titanium.Media.vibrate();  
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    request.open("POST","http://*********/callback.php");  
    var params = {  
        "token": e.deviceToken,
        "username": authProperties[0].username,
        "userId": authProperties[0].userId    
    };  

    request.send(params);

    //  Message data for the inbox
    var inboxData = data.inbox;     

    Titanium.App.properties.setString("badgeCount",data.badge);

    var badge = data.badge;  
    if(badge > 0){  
        Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = 202;//badge;  
    }  

    var message = data.message;
    if(message != ''){  
        var my_alert=Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'',message:JSON.stringify(inboxData) });

        my_alert.show();  
    }  
}  
});
```

The following script handles the php part of the push notification:

```
$serverId = "81273";  
    $name = "APNS";  
    $apnsPort = 2195;//5223;  
    $passPhrase = "";  
    $fwrite = "";  
    $sslUrl = "ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:" . $apnsPort;  
    $apnsCert = "./apns-distr.pem";//give the apns.pem file path on your server  
    $badge = 22;
$message = "[". date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . '] Er is een nieuw bericht voor u.';  
$inboxArray = array();
$inboxArray["id"]= 1;
$inboxArray["message"] = "Dit bericht dient als test";
$inboxArray["date"] = date("d-m-Y h:i:s");
$apnspayload['aps'] = array ('alert' => $message,'badge' => $badge,'sound' => 'default', 'inbox' => $inboxArray);  

$payload = json_encode($apnspayload);  

$tokens = array();
$tokens[] = "********** ** * * *";

foreach($tokens as $tokenId){


    $apnsMessage = chr(1) . pack('N', time()) . pack('N', time() + 86400) . chr(0) . chr(32) 
        . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $tokenId)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;  

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();  

    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);  
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passPhrase);  

    $apns = stream_socket_client($sslUrl, $error, $errorString, 6, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);  

    if($apns){  
        $fwrite = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);  

        fclose($apns);  
        @socket_close($apns);  
    }else{  
        echo 'request failed';  
    }  
}`
```

Comment: This question seems at odds with your more recent question where you're wondering how to avoid the callback firing in all of your contexts... Have you solved this, then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231470/titanium-mobile-apple-push-notifications-what-is-the-most-logical-place-to-ins

Comment: The question you mention is solved and a different one rised.. It seemed something is wrong with Parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved,

It seems something with the JSON went wrong, still not sure what.

In the App.js: 
`var data = JSON.parse(e.data);` upon removing the `JSON.parse()` the code worked.
For some reason the JSON data did not need to be parsed.. thus the line became `var data = e.data;`