# Titanium mobile / Apple Push notifications What is the most logical place to insert the callback

Tags: titanium, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, titanium-mobile

Question,

What I want to achieve is to have a centralised place for the notifications to be received, so no matter on what window or tab a user is the notification will be received and callback functions to be fired.

If a project relies heavily on the Apple Push Notifications what would (In Titanium Mobile) be the best place to insert the code for the notification requests and callback.

I thought this would happen automatically but it does not, currently I have the registerForPushNotifications placed in a file that is included on every window & tab. But if a push notification is send then it is received on every tab, but if I change the tab the notification is again received.

So if I place the `registerForPushNotifications` on a included file the notification will be received numerous times even tough it is fired once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said about your code, you're having trouble because you have multiple execution contexts (i.e. every tab has a window with the url property to another JavaScript file). Rather than using multiple contexts, load up the windows in a single context (using at least CommonJS, and optimally Alloy). Then you can register your callback in app.js, or in a CommonJS module called from your app.js. Your problem wouldn't exist in that scenario.

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake. I initially wanted the push notifications to be fired after user login, so I placed the code in the window after login. I have not used CommonJS, would you recommend using it on smaller projects?

Comment: I'd recommend using it on any project. :) Here's a link to the blog post: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/12/commonjs-module-guide-for-1-8.html and here's a gist I just made for you to help you get started: https://gist.github.com/4503143

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I have been trying to search for good examples but this is definitely the best!

Comment: in your opinion with Titanium Mobile 3.0. Would you say Alloy or still CommonJS? I am now using Titanium Mobile 2.x.x I am going to update to 3.0 for upcoming projects.

Comment: Alloy is built on top of CommonJS. It's important to understand both.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will investigate both for further projects, but first this!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using push notifications with ACS, look here http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135751/acs---push-notifications---tutorial

more information here

http://blog.teemusk.com/2012/05/building-server-push-notifications-with-appcelerator-titanium-cloud/